# "Until you do" vs "until you won't" vs "until you don't"?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> Your kids won’t change for the better **until you change**.

vs

> Your kids won’t change for the better **until you don't change**.

vs

> Your kids won’t change for the better **until you won't change**.

Which is sensible and well grammatically?

Comment: What are you trying to say in the sentence?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I mean that in the first place the person I speak to should change own behavior, otherwise their kids won't change

Comment: In fact, we don't say 'until something doesn't happen' so the second and third sentences are not proper English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first sentence means 'Your kids won't change if you don't change'. The other two don't mean anything. They resemble a French construction like 'Je vais rentrer avant qu'il ne fasse nuit', where 'ne' looks negative. We don't that in English.